# array_merge_recursive on multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Please how do i apply array_merge_recursive on the code below

```
<?php
array:4 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
              1 => "1_1"       
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
              1 => "1_2"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [▼
              2 => "2_1"
  ]
 3 => array:1 [▼
              2 => "2_2"
  ]
]
?>
```

I need the output to be

```
<?php
array:2 [▼
 0 => array:2 [▼
   0 => "1_1",
   1 => "1_2"
 ]
 1 => array:2 [▼
   0 => "2_1",
   1 => "2_2"
 ]
 ]
 ?>
```

**Note: the inner array might increase from 4 to 1000**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Short and to the point.

```
$array = [
  0 => [
    0 => '1_1',
  ],
  1=> [
    0 => '1_2',
  ],
  2 => [
    0 => '2_1',
  ],
  3 => [
    0 => '2_2',
  ],
];

foreach(array_chunk($array, 2) as $value){
  print_r(array_merge(array_shift($value), array_pop($value)));
}
```

---

Get a chunk of 2 from the big array. Loop over the chunks, get the first element in the array and the last element and merge them.

---

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1_1
    [1] => 1_2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2_1
    [1] => 2_2
)
```

---

Remove the `print_r` and adapt to your own needs.

`array_merge_recursive` can also be used instead of `array_merge` but it this case it does exactly the same thing. You'd still need to somehow get the chunks.

Comment: it did not work. this is the output   - array:2 [▼
  0 => "2_1"
  1 => "2_2"
]

Comment: As I said, adapt to your own needs. The code works just fine, you're not using it in the right context. Take a little time to understand what it does.

Comment: Yeah thanks, but the chunk of 2 is the problem. What of if some are 2 and some are 6. It is not static they are options selected

Comment: In the context of current array using `array_merge_recursive` is tricky. Mostly because all the keys are different, so there's no way to know which sub array should be merged with what. You'd still need to figure that part out firstly.

Comment: Please do you have any solution for me?

Comment: Hang on a minute. You said they are option selected. Post your html, if it's how I think it is, there's a easier solution to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126302/discussion-between-odin-and-andrew).